# switching to worker mpm for apache 2 on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, performance-tuning, mpm-worker, mpm-prefork

How to switch from prefork mpm to worker mpm on ubuntu server?
how to roll back if there is any problem?

```
    root@myserver:~# apache2ctl -l
Compiled in modules:
core.c
mod_log_config.c
mod_logio.c
prefork.c
http_core.c
mod_so.c
root@myserver:~# aptitude search apache2-mpm-
p   apache2-mpm-event                                                      - Event driven model for Apache HTTPD
p   apache2-mpm-itk                                                        - multiuser MPM for Apache 2.2
p   apache2-mpm-perchild                                                   - Transitional package - please remove
i A apache2-mpm-prefork                                                    - Traditional model for Apache HTTPD
p   apache2-mpm-worker                                                     - High speed threaded model for Apache HTTPD
root@myserver:~#
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you will be changing your configuration it would be advisable to backup your current configuration befor your install:

```
$ cp -R /etc/apache2 ~/backup
$ sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-worker
```

If you run into problems you can

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork
$ cp -R ~/backup /etc/apache2
```

Comment: On Ubuntu Server 14.04 I had to manually disable `mpm-event` and enable `mpm-worker` like this: `sudo a2dismod mpm_event && sudo a2enmod mpm_worker && sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

Just install the package `apache2-mpm-worker`. If you have any problem with it, just install the package `apache2-mpm-prefork` again.

Also note that they are mutually exclusive. You can't install them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this great tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-apache-http-with-mpm-event-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04